# Bootstrap navbar overflow issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap navbar with multilevel hover support.

Issue showcase: https://www.bootply.com/cXwBPibI6V

The problem I'm stuggling with is that my `hover:`div (*test 1* element) is not placed outside its parent div. When I remove the `overflow` property, it works as intended. But on my website this div consists of 100 elements and so actually has to be set up with a scrollbar.

How could one fix this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMw61.jpg

Comment: Maybe you would have to make this scroll with CSS and JS style instead of using the browser default scroll, because I think there is no way to achieve this in a simple way.

Comment: I don't get why this scrollbar messes up the whole thing. So you mean I should search for some standalone scrollbar frameworks?

Comment: The behaviour of the native browser scroll needs overflow property to be set and because this you can't do make appear the submenus.

Comment: You are required to post your markup here, not a third party site that can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one in the future: [mcve]

Comment: ...so you want to horizontally scroll? Because I can scroll horizontally with it..but then again I can omni scroll, so I don't have to click the bar to scroll over. Are you wanting to be able to click and move a horizontal scroll bar over? If so, then those submenu items will need to become toggles, so that way each submenu stays open and you can go and move the scrollbar.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke I want to hover this element in order to popup the next tier div right next to it, but out of its parent div.

Comment: @Revo So what portion needs to scroll?

Comment: the div that opens as soon as I hover something. imagine I had like 100 features in there. each element should open a new div next to it and so on.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke https://imgur.com/a/SOCGt

Comment: If you want to scroll in the second hover menu, how about just moving the `overflow:scroll` to the next level? as in `.dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu{
     overflow:scroll; 
    }  `

Comment: @PaigeMeinke but both level's div heights are too large